# Quarkus Manually Set Open API Url

Tags: swagger-ui, quarkus

So I know I can change the open api path with quarkus.smallrye-openapi.path=/openapi

However I am using an api gateway and at the beginning of my services I identify them with something like https://gateurl/notification/swagger-ui/

How do I change the url for open api so I don't have to manually put /notification/openapi in swagger each time I open the url

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `quarkus.swagger-ui.urls` to set one or more urls. See https://quarkus.io/guides/openapi-swaggerui#quarkus-swaggerui_quarkus.swagger-ui.urls-urls

Example:

```
quarkus.swagger-ui.urls.default=https://gateurl/notification/swagger-ui/
```

This will change the url as you want it.

You can also add both (one that goes through the gateway and one direct for example):

```
quarkus.swagger-ui.urls.default=https://gateurl/notification/swagger-ui/
quarkus.swagger-ui.urls.direct=/q/openapi
quarkus.swagger-ui.urls-primary-name=default
```

This will give you a dropdown with the gateway one selected by default.

See https://github.com/phillip-kruger/openapi-example for a example.

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I want!

Answer (score 0):

Use the setting `quarkus.smallrye-openapi.additional-docs-directory=META-INF/` in the `application.properties` and all the .json files underneath will be discovered automatically.